# Transactional Mail Extension Problem

Tags: civimail, extension

I installed the Transactional Mail Extension and after adjusting a needed Drupal CiviMail permission got it working.

After testing, I deleted the Transactional Mail pseudo mailing, to start fresh, but find that after doing that I get the yellow-screen-of-death and a missing ID error when an event registration or contribution is submitted.  I disabled the extension for now-- how do I fix this?

Also, oddly in my tests, each sent email had a duplicate record with an unknown status.  Anyone know why?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Larry - welcome to Civi SE!  It would probably be helpful for folks if you could include what versions of CiviCRM and Drupal you're using (as well as the extension version).

Comment: Hi Larry. As well as the CiviCRM and drupal versions could you include the version of the extension you are using. I've just tried following you steps above (first by deleting a specific Transactional Mail pseudo mailing, then by deleting all of them). I wasn't able to replicate the error message. If you are able to identify the error in your civicrm ConfigAndLog log file that would be great too. There is a great extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer that enables you to easily view this file, that I would recommend installing if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks-- we are on Drupal 7.61 and CiviCRM 5.4.0.  The Transactional Mail extension is 1.0.1.  

I did find this warning in the log: Nov 27 21:44:51  [warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (transactional_mailings) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems

Comment: are you on PHP 7.1 (or greater) by any chance? I've tracked down that depreciation warning and it looks to have been introduced to cope with changes in php. (Feel free to @ me in the reply so I get notified)

Comment: Larry - can you paste the error statement that you get after event registration or after submitting the contribution?

Comment: Also - are you using the updated zip downloaded from https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional? There were some fixes done recently to the extension eg https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional/pull/26

Comment: @luke-stewart: We are still on PHP 5.6.31.  Planning to upgrade soon.

Comment: The error we get is:  Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
job_id is not valid : 16895

Comment: Yes, using 1.0.1 from GitHub with 5/14/2018 dates.

Comment: @LarryK. It seems related to the issue fixed https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional/pull/26. Can you apply this patch and try again?

Comment: Or else you can click https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional/archive/master.zip link and replace your extension with the same.

Comment: OK-- I removed the extension and replaced the existing files with the new ones, however now the extension list says it in not installed, and when I try to reinstall, I get a yellow screen: DB Error: already exists.  If I remove the folder and try to reinstall from Drush, I get Extension nz.co.fuzion.transactional could not be installed.

Comment: @LarryK. The error during re-installation was a known problem which got fixed in https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional/pull/36. Can you get the master version again and install https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional/archive/master.zip?